# Spring MVC RequestMapping confusion

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm having trouble with Spring MVC RequestMapping and I'm hoping someone can give me advice on how to proceed.

I'm working on a server that will be accessed by a legacy client.  The client sends simple requests (see below) but cannot be changed in any way to accommodate the new server.

The client sends gets or posts of the form  */dbintf?command=GETINFO,acctNum=111*
The server is called dbintf and it returns a simple text response.

I would like to create a Spring controller for each command and annotate a single controller method with
a params mapping that is based on the command parameter.  So the mapping in the GETINFOController would be:

```
@RequestMapping(params="command=GETINFO")
public String serviceRequest(....
```

However, I cannot get this to work.  Here are some details of the service.

The servlet mapping in web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dbintf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The annotation scanning directives in intf-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.intf.controller" />   
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

I have been trying various combinations  of things to  try to  get this scheme to work and I'll  boil this
trial-and-error work down to two  examples:

This does not work. The response is: "The requested resource () is not available."

```
@RequestMapping( params="command=GETINFO")
public class TESTController  {
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String serviceRequest
```

If I change the url to add another level: /dbintf/test?command=GETINFO,acctNum=111
it works if I add a URL pattern to the handler method annotation.

```
@RequestMapping( params="command=GETINFO")
public class TESTController  {
    @RequestMapping( value="/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String serviceRequest
```

This makes me think that params mapping alone will not work.  It appears that a URL
pattern must be part of any mapping scheme.  For my case however, there is no
URL pattern available since the the client request URL is fixed as: *dbintf?....*.
My question: is it possible to use parameter based mapping alone and not
in conjunction with a pattern?  If so, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice,
beeky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your config where you are mapping your controllers to "/dbintf"? You've got your DispatcherServlet (assuming that "dbintf" servlet is your DispatcherServlet) mapped to just "/", not "/dbintf". Are you deploying your webapp so that it's available at "/dbintf" relative to your container's "/"? I guess what I'm trying to get at is that you may just need to add some config to your @RequestMapping's:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dbintf", params="command=GETINFO")
```